# Navbar underline hover animation

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make a hover animation that has an underline line appearing when the mouse is over it.

what can i add to achieve that? i tried the pre made ones but it didn't work. it showed an line appearing but not under the navbar text but under the website itself (on the bottom of the screen).

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  padding: 40px 16px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

li a:hover {
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-nav {
  background-color: tomato;
}

#logo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mob-Mob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 139px;" id="logo"></a>
      <li style="float: right;" class="hover-nav"><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply the `transition` to the element, not its hover state. With `transition` you are telling telling the element how to behave if anything changes. In this case all styles (that are susceptible to a transition) for a period of 0.3 seconds with an ease-in-out speed curve.

Then use the `:hover` selector to indicate what changes need to be made. So in this case change the background color and add an underline to the text.

Also avoid using inline styles when possible.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
 }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  li {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  }

  li a:hover {
      background-color: tomato;
      text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you intended to apply an underline to the bottom of the box instead of the text you can use `border-bottom` and makes sure to use `box-sizing: border box` so your element will remain the same size when the border gets added.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: grey;
 }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 100px;
  }
  
  li {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
  }
  
  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 40px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 2.5px;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100px;
  }

  li a:hover {
      background-color: tomato;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted and possibly vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, I marked my edits on your css code.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

li {
  padding: 40px 16px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

li a:hover {
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}


/*Edit starts here*/
li {
  position:relative;
}

li::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0077ff;
    transition: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1) 1s;
}

li:hover::after {
    width: 80%;
    left: 10%;
}

li {
  transition: cubic-bezier(.77,0,.18,1) 1s;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
}

/*Edit ends here*/

#logo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mob-Mob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 139px;" id="logo"></a>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
      <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-decoration:underline` to your `li:hover` code like this...

```
li a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code **Invalid** you added `<a>` section in `<ul>` without `<li>` tag

```
<ul>
  <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 139px;" id="logo"></a>
  <li style="float: right;" class="hover-nav"><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
</ul>
```

changes to

```
<ul>
  <li><a href=""><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" style="width: 139px;" id="logo"></a></li>
  <li style="float: right;" class="hover-nav"><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
  <li style="float: right;"><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Edit in CSS:**

```
ul {      
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
li {
  width:100%; // remove padding and add to `li a`.
}
li a{
  border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
  height: 100px !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
li a:hover { // instead of .hover-nav
  background-color: tomato;
  border-bottom:4px solid #fff;
}
// remove #logo margin
```

**Working Demo**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

li {
  width:100%;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  border-bottom:4px solid transparent;
  height: 100px !important;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

li a:hover {
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: tomato;
  border-bottom:4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mob-Mob</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href=""><img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/52d41e/fff&text=Logo" alt="" style="width:100%;" id="logo"></a></li>
      <li class="hover-nav"><a href="">კონტაქტი</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ჩვენს შესახებ</a></li>
      <li><a href="">ქეისები</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```